# Sql Query or Join for 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have tables:

```
User Table
User_id| Preferences |Blood_Group|City

Events Table
Event_id|Event_type|Blood_Group|Event_city|Event_Addded_By|Description

Commit Table
User_id|Event_id
```

I will send the user_id so that,I want a query  to return those events  which are the events as prefered by user and blood_group and city in event table is same as those values in user table and that event has not been commited by user in commit table.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Well I tried nested query and did implement it to give me my desired result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT        [User Table].User_id, [Events Table].*
FROM            [Commit Table] INNER JOIN
                         [User Table] ON [Commit Table].User_id = [User Table].User_id INNER JOIN
                         [Events Table] ON [Commit Table].Event_id = [Events Table].Event_id
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help you:

```
SELECT [Required Columns] 
FROM [User Table] UT JOIN [Event Table] ET 
ON ET.Bloodgroup = UT.Bloodgroup 
AND ET.City = UT.City 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM [Commit Table] CT 
   WHERE CT.UserId = UT.UserId 
   AND ET.EventId = CT.EventId
)
AND UT.UserId = @UserId
```

Comment: Might help more if you expanded on the above.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you can passing user id. like this

```
select * from events a
join commit b on a.event_id=b.event_id
join user c on b.User_id= c.User_id
where c.User_id=2 and c.Blood_Group=a.Blood_Group and c.City=a.Event_city
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM User INNER JOIN Events ON User.Blood_Group=Events.Blood_Group AND User.City=Events.Event_city LEFT JOIN Commit ON Commit.User_id=User.User_id AND Commit.Event_id=Events.Event_id WHERE User.User_id='<user id here>' AND Commit.User_id IS NULL
```

I understand that you might be a beginner my friend, try reading the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index.html) more often, And don't be afraid to try and experiment with mysql queries, just don't expirement on live production database :D.

Comment: I tried something like this:

select * from events where blood_type=(select blood_group from users where user_id='11') AND event_city=(select city from users where user_id='11') AND event_id NOT in (select event_id from [commit] where user_id='11')

Comment: Always bare in mind that if 'possible' avoid nested queries, like alot of select statement inside select statement, always find a way to make your query have a lesser load for mysql. Learn query optimization   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-optimization.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select e.*
from Events e
join user u  on 
e.Blood_Group = u.Blood_Group and 
e.City = u.City
where 
u.User_id = your_Id and 
e.Event_id not in (select Event_id from Commit)
```